# ¿Cómo usar correctamente el Fetchone para alimentar un comboBox en Python?

Tags: python, mysql, pyqt5, combobox

Tengo una tabla Articulo, de la cual la columna Moldes tiene varias repeticiones, deseo tomar esta columna para un combobox pero sin repeticiones. El problema es que el combobox solo coge el primer registro e ignora a los demás. No lo entiendo. Me podría decir en qué me equivoqué.

```
def molde(self):
    cur=conn.cursor()   
    sql = "SELECT DISTINCT molde FROM articulo"
    data=cur.execute(sql)
    result=cur.fetchone()
    for x in result:
        self.comboBox.addItem(x)
```

Comment: En el título has puesto `fetchone` pero en el código está `fetchall`. Con `fetchall` debería funcionarte.

Comment: @ChemaCortes Me equivoqué al digitar. Ya lo corregí a fechtone. Con fechtall no trabaja porque exige una tupla pero yo solo tengo un dato 'x' a mostrar ('moldes'). Por eso uso fechtone pero solo me arroja al comboBox un valor y no los 10 que debería.

Comment: Creo que estás confundido en cómo funcionan. Ambos, `fetchone()` y `fetchall()`, retornan una tupla por registro devuelto. `fetchone()` sólo devuelve el primero, mientras que `fetchall()` devuelve una lista de todos los registros. Si no lo ves claro, te pongo un ejemplo.

Comment: @ChemaCortes Tienes razón. Debí usar fechtall(). Por otro lado, no quisiera usar DISTINCT. ¿Sabes como hacer para que por medio de instrucciones pyqt5 el comboBox no tenga valores repetidos?

Comment: Es más eficiente que la base de datos haga el `DISTINCT`, además de reducir la cantidad de datos que hay que transmitir. En python se haría usando conjuntos (`set()`) para obtener una lista de elementos únicos.

Comment: @ChemaCortes. Claro. He visto que aplican el set() pero no he visto como aplicarla a comboBox. Me podría dar un ejemplo aplicado a:  self.comboBox.addItem(str(x),y)

Comment: ¿Y de dónde sacas el segundo parámetro?¿Podrías completar mejor el código de la pregunta para ver de dónde proviene?